# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки в QLabel поместить результат расчета уравнения

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout, qlabel, qlineedit

Я хочу в рамках школьного проекта создать программу с помощью *PyQt5*, которая будет решать квадратные уравнения.

Сейчас я застрял на том, как сделать так, чтобы текст в табличке поменялся на значение дискриминанта при нажатии на кнопку.

```
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys
import math
import os
this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
file = os.path.join(this_dir, 'file_name')

a, b, c = map(int, input("Введите a, b, c").split(" "))

D=b*b-4*a*c
d=math.sqrt(D)
x1=(-1*b-d)/2
x2=(-1*b+d)/2

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Решение квадратного уравнения")
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400 ,250)

        self.mt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.mt.setText("Введите a, b, c:")
        self.mt.adjustSize()
        self.mt.move(50, 20)

        self.mt1 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.mt1.move(50, 40)
        self.mt1.setFixedWidth(100)

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.setText("Рассчитать")
        self.btn.adjustSize()
        self.btn.move(160, 40)
        self.btn.setFixedHeight(30)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.calc)


        self.lb = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.lb.move(50, 100)
        self.lb.setText("3..2..1...")
        self.lb.adjustSize()

    def calc(self):
        
        self.lb.adjustSize()            

        self.lb.setText("d=", d, "x1=", x1, "x2=", x2)
        


     
 

def application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application()
```

Я пробовал заменить `QLabel` на `QTextEdit` или что-то еще, но всегда получается только изменить текст на другой, но никак не на значение.

И еще я пытался сделать это вот так:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'квадратное_полное.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
import math

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(367, 191)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(141, 158, 180);\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lprint = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lprint.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 171, 41))
        self.lprint.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 75 8pt \"Myanmar Text\";\n"
"font: 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"font: 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);")
        self.lprint.setObjectName("lprint")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 120, 91, 41))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.tba = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.tba.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 71, 41))
        self.tba.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.tba.setObjectName("tba")
        self.tbb = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.tbb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 60, 71, 41))
        self.tbb.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.tbb.setObjectName("tbb")
        self.tbc = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.tbc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 60, 71, 41))
        self.tbc.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.tbc.setObjectName("tbc")
        self.la = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.la.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 47, 31))
        self.la.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.la.setObjectName("la")
        self.lb = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 20, 47, 31))
        self.lb.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.lb.setObjectName("lb")
        self.lc = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 20, 47, 31))
        self.lc.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.lc.setObjectName("lc")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lprint.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "D=  , x1=  ,x2=  "))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.la.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "a="))
        self.lb.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "c="))
        self.lc.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "b="))
        self.tba.setReadOnly(False)
        self.tbb.setReadOnly(False)
        self.tbc.setReadOnly(False)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.tbclick)
       


    def tbclick(self):
        try:
            a = float(self.tba.text()) \
                    if self.tba.text() else 1
            b = float(self.tbb.text()) \
                    if self.tbb.text() else 1  
            c = float(self.tbc.text()) \
                    if self.tbc.text() else 1                    
        except:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Проверьте правильность заполнения коэффициентов.'
            )
            return
            
        discr = (b*b) - (4*a*c) 
        if discr > 0:
            x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(discr)) / (2 * a)
            x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(discr)) / (2 * a)
            rez = f"x1 = {x1:.2f};\nx2 = {x2:.2f};"
        elif discr == 0:
            x = -b / (2 * a)
            rez = f"x = {x:.2f};"
        else:
            rez = "Корней нет" 
        self.lprint.setText(rez)
                    
    
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но при вводе чисел выводится что-то не то:

[image: Но при вводе чисел выводится что-то не то:]

Изучать *PyQt5* начал недавно простите за глупые ошибки.

Comment: и еще как бы продолжение этого вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1493219/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-py-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pyqt5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-py-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pyqt5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
import math
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, \
    QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
    QMessageBox, QApplication, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon, QPixmap


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.create_all_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.heading_label = QLabel('Решение квадратного уравнения')
        self.heading_label.setFont(QFont('Times', 13, QFont.Bold))
        self.heading_label.setStyleSheet(
            'border: 3px solid green; border-radius: 5px;')
        
        self.entering_label = QLabel('Введите коэффициенты:')
        self.entering_label.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))

        self.a_value = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Значение a')
        self.b_value = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Значение b')
        self.c_value = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Значение c')
        
        self.rez_label = QLabel() 
        self.rez_label.setMinimumHeight(50)
        self.rez_label.setFont(QFont('Times', 15, QFont.Bold))

        self.find_button = QPushButton('Найти')
        self.clear_button = QPushButton('Очистить')

    def create_layers(self):
        v_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        v_layout.addWidget(self.heading_label)

        self.groupBox = QGroupBox(self.entering_label.text())
        self.groupBox.setStyleSheet('''
            QGroupBox {
                margin-top: 2ex;
            }
            QGroupBox:enabled {
                border: 3px solid green;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
            QGroupBox::title {
                subcontrol-origin: margin;
                left: 3ex;
            }
        ''')
        group_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.groupBox)
        group_layout.addWidget(self.a_value)
        group_layout.addWidget(self.b_value)
        group_layout.addWidget(self.c_value)
        v_layout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        
        v_layout.addWidget(self.rez_label)
        
        h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        h_layout.addWidget(self.find_button)
        h_layout.addWidget(self.clear_button)
        v_layout.addLayout(h_layout)  


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.fb = FormBuilder()
        self.fb.find_button.clicked.connect(self.calc)
        self.fb.clear_button.clicked.connect(self.clear_form)

        self.main_layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.fb, 0, 0, Qt.AlignTop)

    def calc(self):
        try:
            a = float(self.fb.a_value.text()) \
                    if self.fb.a_value.text() else 1
            b = float(self.fb.b_value.text()) \
                    if self.fb.b_value.text() else 1  
            c = float(self.fb.c_value.text()) \
                    if self.fb.c_value.text() else 1                    
        except:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Проверьте правильность заполгения коэффициентов.'
            )
            return
            
        discr = (b*b) - (4*a*c) 
        if discr > 0:
            x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(discr)) / (2 * a)
            x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(discr)) / (2 * a)
            rez = f"x1 = {x1:.2f};\nx2 = {x2:.2f}"
        elif discr == 0:
            x = -b / (2 * a)
            rez = f"x = {x:.2f};"
        else:
            rez = "Корней нет" 
        self.fb.rez_label.setText(rez)
                    
    def clear_form(self):
        self.fb.rez_label.clear()
        self.fb.a_value.clear()
        self.fb.b_value.clear()
        self.fb.c_value.clear()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('КВУР')
    w.resize(400, 250)
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon('lena-2.png'))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спросите если что-то не понятно.

Comment: @MedYar что не так?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все в целом понятно, но не могли бы вы поделиться источником или объяснить основы работы с layers и groupbox, командами try, return, AlignTop и Qfont и для чего фигурные скобки и что такое `rez = f"x1 = {x1:.2f};\nx2 = {x2:.2f}"` и `rez = f"x = {x:.2f};"`.

Comment: @MedYar    https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html , https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgroupbox.html и так далее. И еще, если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: и еще `a = float(self.fb.a_value.text()) \
                    if self.fb.a_value.text() else 1` это часть команды try или это уже отдельно вид if else?

Comment: @MedYar `a = float(self.fb.a_value.text()) if self.fb.a_value.text() else 1`  
это одна операция: переменной `a` присвоить значение `float(self.fb.a_value.text())` 
если в `self.fb.a_value.text()` что-то написано и иначе (если ничего не написано) 
присвоить значение `1` (один). 
Python Try Except https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp 
это уже другое, если вы введете в какую-нибудь `lineEdit` вместо 
числа, например букву, то сработает эта конструкция и вы получите сообщение 
`'Проверьте правильность заполнения коэффициентов.'`.

Comment: А все вычисления начинаются здесь `def calc(self):` или есть какие-либо команды, которые отвечают за рассчеты выше?

Comment: @MedYar ,  да, после того как вы ввели коэффициенты и нажали кнопку 'Найти' , все вычисления начинаются здесь `def calc(self)`. The End.