# Как можно открыть один файл .py на PyQt5 через другой файл .py на PyQt5?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qprocess

Я хочу создать программу на *PyQt5* с решением разных математических задач, 
здесь есть только код для квадратного уравнения, который должен активироваться при нажатии на кнопу Уравнения (`self.urav`).

Это код для основной программы: **main.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'основа.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, \
        QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
        QMessageBox, QApplication, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon, QPixmap
import math
import sys
import os
import sqrt


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(272, 253)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(215, 253, 255);\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, -10, 421, 351))
        self.groupBox.setStyleSheet("")
        self.groupBox.setTitle("")
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.urav = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.urav.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 221, 31))
        self.urav.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"font: 75 8pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"font: 75 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 225);\n"
"alternate-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);\n"
"selection-color: rgb(247, 255, 190);\n"
"border: 3px solid green; border-radius: 5px;")
        self.urav.setObjectName("urav")
        self.plos = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.plos.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 221, 31))
        self.plos.setStyleSheet("font: 75 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 225);\n"
"alternate-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);\n"
"selection-color: rgb(247, 255, 190);\n"
"border: 3px solid green; border-radius: 5px;")
        self.plos.setObjectName("plos")
        self.progr = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.progr.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 150, 221, 31))
        self.progr.setStyleSheet("font: 75 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 225);\n"
"alternate-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);\n"
"selection-color: rgb(247, 255, 190);\n"
"border: 3px solid green; border-radius: 5px;")
        self.progr.setObjectName("progr")
        self.proc = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.proc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 221, 31))
        self.proc.setStyleSheet("font: 75 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 225);\n"
"alternate-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);\n"
"selection-color: rgb(247, 255, 190);\n"
"border: 3px solid green; border-radius: 5px;")
        self.proc.setObjectName("proc")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.urav.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Уравнения"))
        self.plos.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Площади"))
        self.progr.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Прогрессии"))
        self.proc.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Проценты"))
        self.urav.clicked.connect(self.urav_clicked)

    def urav_clicked(self):
                os.system('sqrt.py')

        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Это код для решения квадратных уравнений:**sqrt.py**

```
import sys
import os
import math
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, \
    QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
    QMessageBox, QApplication, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon, QPixmap


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.create_all_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.heading_label = QLabel('Решение квадратного уравнения')
        self.heading_label.setFont(QFont('Times', 13, QFont.Bold))
        self.heading_label.setStyleSheet(
            'border: 3px solid green; border-radius: 5px;')
        
        self.entering_label = QLabel('Введите коэффициенты:')
        self.entering_label.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))

        self.a_value = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Значение a')
        self.b_value = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Значение b')
        self.c_value = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Значение c')
        
        self.rez_label = QLabel() 
        self.rez_label.setMinimumHeight(50)
        self.rez_label.setFont(QFont('Times', 15, QFont.Bold))

        self.find_button = QPushButton('Найти')
        self.clear_button = QPushButton('Очистить')

    def create_layers(self):
        v_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        v_layout.addWidget(self.heading_label)

        self.groupBox = QGroupBox(self.entering_label.text())
        self.groupBox.setStyleSheet('''
            QGroupBox {
                margin-top: 2ex;
            }
            QGroupBox:enabled {
                border: 3px solid green;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
            QGroupBox::title {
                subcontrol-origin: margin;
                left: 3ex;
            }
        ''')
        group_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.groupBox)
        group_layout.addWidget(self.a_value)
        group_layout.addWidget(self.b_value)
        group_layout.addWidget(self.c_value)
        v_layout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        
        v_layout.addWidget(self.rez_label)
        
        h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        h_layout.addWidget(self.find_button)
        h_layout.addWidget(self.clear_button)
        v_layout.addLayout(h_layout)  


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.fb = FormBuilder()
        self.fb.find_button.clicked.connect(self.calc)
        self.fb.clear_button.clicked.connect(self.clear_form)

        self.main_layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.fb, 0, 0, Qt.AlignTop)

    def calc(self):
        try:
            a = float(self.fb.a_value.text()) \
                    if self.fb.a_value.text() else 1
            b = float(self.fb.b_value.text()) \
                    if self.fb.b_value.text() else 1  
            c = float(self.fb.c_value.text()) \
                    if self.fb.c_value.text() else 1                    
        except:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Проверьте правильность заполнения коэффициентов.'
            )
            return
            
        discr = (b*b) - (4*a*c) 
        if discr > 0:
            x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(discr)) / (2 * a)
            x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(discr)) / (2 * a)
            rez = f"x1 = {x1:.2f};\nx2 = {x2:.2f};"
        elif discr == 0:
            x = -b / (2 * a)
            rez = f"x = {x:.2f};"
        else:
            rez = "Корней нет" 
        self.fb.rez_label.setText(rez)
                    
    def clear_form(self):
        self.fb.rez_label.clear()
        self.fb.a_value.clear()
        self.fb.b_value.clear()
        self.fb.c_value.clear()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app1 = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('КВУР')
    w.resize(400, 250)
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon('lena-2.png'))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app1.exec_())
```

[image: Здесь я пытался открыть код sqrt.py через os.system но появляется ошибка в терминале]

Comment: вы хотите заблокировать основное окно или нет ? может вы хотите, чтобы основное окно исчезло ? уточните детали

Comment: Нет, мне нужно чтобы можно было выбирать между кнопками и в случае закрытия одного окна можно было открыть другое например запустить основа.py там выбрать квадратные и после работы с sqrt.py можно было вернуться в основу и выбрать что-то другое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА.** 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Класс [**QProcess**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html) используется для запуска внешних программ и взаимодействия с ними.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(272, 253)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(215, 253, 255);\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, -10, 421, 351))
        self.groupBox.setStyleSheet("")
        self.groupBox.setTitle("")
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.urav = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.urav.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 221, 31))
        self.urav.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"font: 75 8pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"font: 75 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 225);\n"
"alternate-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);\n"
"selection-color: rgb(247, 255, 190);\n"
"border: 3px solid green; border-radius: 5px;")
        self.urav.setObjectName("urav")
        self.plos = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.plos.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 221, 31))
        self.plos.setStyleSheet("font: 75 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 225);\n"
"alternate-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);\n"
"selection-color: rgb(247, 255, 190);\n"
"border: 3px solid green; border-radius: 5px;")
        self.plos.setObjectName("plos")
        self.progr = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.progr.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 150, 221, 31))
        self.progr.setStyleSheet("font: 75 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 225);\n"
"alternate-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);\n"
"selection-color: rgb(247, 255, 190);\n"
"border: 3px solid green; border-radius: 5px;")
        self.progr.setObjectName("progr")
        self.proc = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.proc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 221, 31))
        self.proc.setStyleSheet("font: 75 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 225);\n"
"alternate-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);\n"
"selection-color: rgb(247, 255, 190);\n"
"border: 3px solid green; border-radius: 5px;")
        self.proc.setObjectName("proc")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.urav.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Уравнения"))
        self.plos.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Площади"))
        self.progr.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Прогрессии"))
        self.proc.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Проценты"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.urav.clicked.connect(self.urav_clicked)

        self.process = QtCore.QProcess()                             # <-------
        self.process.setProcessChannelMode(QtCore.QProcess.MergedChannels)
        

    def urav_clicked(self):
#        os.system('q1493219_sqrt.py')    # sqrt.py
        self.process.start("python", ["-u", "q1493219_sqrt.py"])
   
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Не могли бы объяснить эти моменты:`self.process.setProcessChannelMode(QtCore.QProcess.MergedChannels)`, `#        os.system('q1493219_sqrt.py')    # sqrt.py
        self.process.start("python", ["-u", "q1493219_sqrt.py"])`

Comment: @MedYar `os.system('q1493219_sqrt.py')` блокирует интерфейс, его использовать не надо. Ссылку на класс `QProcess` я вам сбросил, читайте.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный и полезный, если выне знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: А ведь чтобы преобразовать эти файлы в программу .exe подойдет pyinstaller или auto-py-to-exe?

Comment: @MedYar да, подойдет. На этом ресурсе есть вопросы и ответы как это делать.